# Dynamically loaded javascript of angular not working

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, directive, loaded

I am building an application where my DOM is add dynamically outside of angular world ie. jQuery and also the javascript for that is loaded dynamically. I get $compile from angular.injector method and also the scope and then did used the $compile service. But with all this my directives and controller don't run. I see them added to my app but still controller won't initiated.

index.html is

```
<html>
<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="test">
    <div id="main">

    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<script src="https://googledrive.com/host/0ByYZbKdhSDoSeFNQVGdEd2k3amM/direc.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
//Create angular module
angular.module("test",[]);

$(document).ready(function(){
  //Load dynamically the JS
  $.getScript('https://googledrive.com/host/0ByYZbKdhSDoSeFNQVGdEd2k3amM/direc.js', function(){
   angular.element($("#main")[0]).scope().$root.$apply();
  });
  var scrip = "<script src=\"https://googledrive.com/host/0ByYZbKdhSDoSeFNQVGdEd2k3amM/direc.js\"></script>"
  var htmlStr = "<span test-drective=\"test-drective\">Test</span>";
  $("#main").append(angular.element('*[ng-app]').injector().get("$compile")(htmlStr)(angular.element($("#main")[0]).scope().$new(true)));
})
```

and direc.js is

```
angular.module("test")
.directive("testDrective", function(){
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
    controller: function($scope) {
            console.log("Controller")
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log("link")
        }
  };
})
```

If I add the direc.js in index.html, all works fine but not with the dynamic load of script using jquery or added as part of dom.

Sample app:
https://plnkr.co/edit/gekifqGzJDAsWs5OF4ro

Answer (score 0):

Try to bootstrap your angular app in code after you loading is completed and your DOM is ready `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);`

See [bootstraping angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) section "Manual Initialization"

In general all your javascript code of your angular app must be present at the client. And you should not manipulate the DOM outside directives. Perhaps this [ng-bind-html-compile directive](https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile) helps you to solve your problem in a more angular way